# Raspberry Pi 3 high IO

Tags: pi-3, raspberry-pi-os-buster

my Raspberry Pi 3 is currently suffering from a very high IOWait. Running iotop gives me the following:
[image: screenshot of iotop]

It's listing some perl process but I have no idea what it is or why it's using 99% IO. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update** with info from comments:
I am using Raspberry Pi OS Buster. This version of Raspberry Pi OS is unmodified. Things I have installed: nginx, grafana, collectd, influxdb, minio. The command I ran was just iotop. I have no clue what this perl process could be.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question. What operating system do you use? What version? Have you done some modifications or is it running unmodified from the image?

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind for the future. I am using Raspberry Pi OS Buster. This version of Raspberry Pi OS is unmodified. Things I have installed: nginx, grafana, collectd, influxdb, minio

Comment: Even more importantly, does the image shows a complete command or a truncated command line? It's even more peculiar that your system runs a heavy Perl job as root.

Comment: The command I ran was just iotop. I have no clue what this perl process could be.

Comment: Please don't answer your question within the question. It is not the way this site works. Instead create an answer (just cut and paste the UPDATE to it). There is nothing wrong by answering your question. Please accept then the answer after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again, annoying us for years.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the PID of the offending process (4076), you should find out what started it. Run `ps -aef --forest` (as root, because it's a root process) and search for the PID in the process tree.

The keyword `automake` suggests it could be a software package being installed from source code.

Unless you observe this behavior right after a reboot, check out your `.bash_history` file or whatever. It could be that you have started a software build and then forgot about it.

Comment: 99% IO is now being used by [kworker/u8:0+flush-179:0] which seemingly doesn't make any sense to me. I tried the command you suggested but apparently nothing started this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `automake` definitely = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools So the ultimate cause here was probably something where you ran `./configure` then `make` (or `make install`).

Comment: @Cx24 `kworker` is a kernel thread which is processing system requests. It won't hog your system unless there's an application sending those requests. If you suspect a kernel problem you could try to catch a trace using `echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger` but I don't even know if kernel trace is enabled in the Pi stock kernel. From your screenshot I deduce the problem is with `perl`, and kernel load is just a consequence.

Comment: The problem probably is not that or any particular process at all.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the perl process is oddly completely gone now. However, high IO is still happening. The only two things I can see is jbd2/mmcblk0p2- and [kworker/u8:0+flush-179:0] but also collectd occasionally. I should probably mention that I have an external HDD connected to the Pi via USB mounted with fstab. No clue if my external HDD could somehow be the cause for all this.

Answer (score 2):

The questioner updated his question with the solution. It seems he doesn't like to create a correct answer as suggested in a comment. Here is it:

> After spending a lot of time I finally found the root cause. Collectd auto enabled this on install: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:RRDtool which caused the whole system to use 100% IO for that. Took me way longer to figure out than I'd like to admit. Anyway, my Pi finally seems to be fixed and be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

That `automake` process is not necessarily the cause of the problem, it may instead be mostly a symptom.

> 99% IO is now being used by [kworker/u8:0+flush-179:0] which seemingly doesn't make any sense

First, [WRT `iotop`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282397/25985), the `IO` column shows the percentage of the process's running time that is currently spent waiting on IO.<sup>1</sup>  So 99% for one (or some, or all) process(es) makes sense, it is just concerning.

`[kworker/____]` indicates a kernel thread.  If anything is busy with IO, it is probably the kernel (it could by necessity mean the kernel in the context of `iotop`, that would take some more investigation).

As already mentioned WRT this question, `automake` is a component of [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools), a suite of things used in configuring and executing a software build from source code (usually written in C and/or C++).  If you've done something like this:

```
cd [some_source_direcory]
./configure
make [install]
```

That's what started that. If `automake` and `kworker` are alternating in `iotop` I would guess they are related to each other (ie., the `kworker` is doing stuff for the userland process, `automake`).

In any case, it may be a bit of cause for concern if you have processes constantly waiting on IO this way and your total disk access is ~32 K/s.  It should be a lot faster than that.

This may be because the SD card is wearing out/has developed a defect.  You should have a look at `dmesg` output and int `/var/log/syslog` to see if any IO errors are being issued.

---

1. This implies a sampling period that is presumably quite short. If you want to dive deeper I'd start with that U&L link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My best guess would be that some other process started to compile something. I never compiled anything on my own though. The perl process is gone by now, but jbd2/mmcblk0p2- and [kworker/u8:0+flush-179:0] and collectd still use way too much IO, which slows down the whole OS. My best guess would be that my external HDD is causing this or collectd doing something I'm not aware of.